# Playing audio from characters of a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, textbox

I am a complete noob and I have started trying to do a program which plays the sound of each letter's keycode every time it is pressed in the textbox and deletes the text every time I press the Spacebar.

The program clears the textbox when I use the space button, but it doesn't play sound with any character:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>keyCode example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showKeyCode(e) {
            var letter = e.keyCode

            if (letter != 32)
            {
                var audio = new Audio(e.keyCode + ".wav");
                audio.play();
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input TYPE = text ID="TextBox1" SIZE = 15  onkeyup="showKeyCode(event);">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a few problems in your code:

1. Don't use uppercase tag attributes.
2. Use quotes for attributes.
3. Include the `<body>` tag.
4. You forgot a semicolon after `var letter = e.keyCode`.

   ```
    function showKeyCode(e) {
      var letter = e.keyCode;

      if (letter != 32) {
        var audio = new Audio(e.keyCode + ".wav");
        audio.play();
      } else {
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "";
      }
    }
   ```

I have made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/w9o86q53/2/) for you. It seems to work.

Furthermore, why do you use `onkeyup` and not `onkeydown`?

Comment: Thanks man! yeah, it works perfect now, I used onkeyup because onkeydown leave a space after clearing the textbox